# Unable to convert character array elements as integer elements in C

Tags: c

I am having character array with integer elements for example data[4]={"1234"}. I want to convert it into integer elements . There could be most simple way i.e.subtract 48 from each array element to get corresponding integer number. Here ,I am using atoi() function but not getting expected result.Current output:
1234 ,
234 ,
34 ,
4

Expected output:
1 ,
2 ,
3 ,
4
How should I get it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
  int num0;
  int num1;
  int num2;
  int num3;
  char data[6]={"1234"};

  num0 =atoi(&data[0]);
  printf("num0 =%d\n",num0);

  num1 =atoi(&data[1]);
  printf("num1 =%d\n",num1);

  num2 =atoi(&data[2]);
  printf("num2 =%d\n",num2);

  num3 =atoi(&data[3]);
  printf("num3 =%d\n",num3);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding; `data[4]={"1234"}`  This is wrong.  That literal "1234" takes 5 characters (remember that trailing NUL byte)

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  running the posted code through the compiler results in: *untitled1.c:12:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘atoi’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]*  This is because the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: OT: when initializing an array via a literal, it is (usually) best to let the compiler determine the size of the array.  Suggest:  `char data[] = { "1234" };`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*atoi* uses all the string to do the conversion, not only the first character. Then

- `&data[0]` is `data`being "1234" => `atoi(&data[0])`returns 1234
- `&data[1]` is `data+1`being "234" => `atoi(&data[1])`returns 234
- `&data[2]` is `data+2`being "34" => `atoi(&data[2])`returns 34
- `&data[3]` is `data+3`being "4" => `atoi(&data[3])`returns 4

you want to do something like `data[i] - '0'` where *i* is 0 .. 3

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char data[] = {"1234"}; /* or const char * data = "1234" */
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i != 4; i += 1)
    printf("num%d = %d\n", i+1, data[i] - '0');

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
num1 = 1
num2 = 2
num3 = 3
num4 = 4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Out of that I encourage you to stop to use *atoi* because `atoi("aze")` returns 0 without signaling an error. Instead you can use *strtol* or *scanf* with the format `"%d"` checking *scanf* returns 1.